# Page deleted from WP using OneDrive is still returned in Get Pages OneNote API

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I am guessing the page list has been cached somehow or perhaps it will take awhile for a sync to occur between the OneNote API and the wp client app.

Before deleting the page from a OneNote notebook section - the page is returned using get pages api. Then i delete the page using the OneDrive app on windows phone. Then if I do a get pages again - the deleted page still shows. If I try to access the deleted page from my app - it will show "page not found".

So I would like to stop listing a page that does not exist any more. The response from the get pages does show a no-cache header. But I really don't see any way to control this or force a resync through the OneNote Api. I tried exiting the app and also using a different phone - but the Get pages still returned the deleted page.

If I delete a page directly from my app through the API - it gets deleted and it also no longer shows up when doing a get pages.

thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: at the mercy of the wind..  well, nothing new with forums. So if one gets a listing of available pages from a notebook using the OneNote API and then proceeds to OneNote and deletes the page - reissuing a new Get page query will still return the deleted page as a result. Now I found out that if I go back to OneNote and sync the section of the notebook where the page was - then things work OK. Unless, the deleted page was from a shared notebook. Please Microsoft throw me a line.. thanks.

Comment: The cache should be updated in up to 2 minutes.  From my tests, this usually happens within 30 seconds.
We have a temporary workaround adding the below header to your API request should return the right list of pages:

FavorDataRecency: true

However, we strongly discourage API users from using this header in production as it results in a very slow API call (can even be in the order to tens of seconds) and this header might not be supported in the future.

Comment: Thank you Yaniro.  Assuming the right request (response was OK) - the ghost page title continues to be returned days after I deleted it from OneDrive using either WP 8.1 OneNote or OneDrive app. as follows:  https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages?count=true&expand=parentNotebook,parentSection&FavorDataRecency=true   No delay observed. This happens from any device including those that I had never retrieved a list from. Still not clear why after sync on WP OneNote app - pages deleted by OneNote finally stop showing up in get pages  - but not for a page deleted from a 'Shared notebook'

Comment: FavorDataRecency is a header, not a query string parameter, i should have been more clear.

Comment: hi Yaniro - how do you add a header? I try adding to my HttpClient but fall short.. client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.??? NameValueHeaderValue??? Am I going in the right direction?  Maybe with a little bit of your help?  thanks.

Comment: ok, maybe as simple as client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("FavorDataRecency", "true"); ?  Not sure... but after putting this in code - the list of get pages does not return the deleted page. But, if I include a "search=" clause that includes text in the deleted page's title (it was also in the body) it does return the phantom page still. So did I add the header correctly? and is the search index file a separate problem? thanks....

Comment: The FavorDataRecency header and the search parameter cancel each other out.  Adding the header bypasses the cache but adding the search parameter goes back and uses the cache.